# Sum of reciprocals of prime numbers, using alternating sings

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, prime-numbers, divergent-series, riemann-sum

Does the Sum from N=**1** to N=**∞** of : (-1^(N+1))((1/P(N)), where P(N) is the nth prime number, converge? If so, to what number does it converge?

Or in different terms, does the sum of the reciprocal of primes, where there are alternating signs, converge?

Example: (1/2)-(1/3)+(1/5)-(1/7)+(1/11) . . . = ?

Comment: Yes this partially answers my question,But I would like to know if he series converges to a weird number of if it has some nice answer such as pi/20 or e^-3, etc.

Comment: Did you read the answers there?  Of particular interest is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2329044/123905), which provides all currently known information about the number you ask about.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my questions.