# Alternating Prime Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, prime-numbers, infinity, constants

How can one evaluate this sum:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}/{p_n}$?
I've tried it for myself but didn't get any satifying answer although it does converge. I also can't find this sum anywhere else and not even Wolfram Alpha knows what to do.

Comment: You are asking for a simple closed form for the solution?  Not sure there is one.  Numerically, there is no problem...I get $.26960$ with an error bounded by about $10^{-5}$.

Comment: This sum is very unlikely to have a "nice" form.

Comment: I wonder is there a method to compute it up to, say, 100 or more digits in reasonable time...

Answer (score 0):

I just found an upper bound function by myself.

We redefine the summation as below;

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{p_{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{p_{2n}-p_{2n-1}}{p_{2n}.p_{2n-1}}$$

According to prime number theorem, $\int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{logt} \sim π(x)$.
When we take the derivative of both sides we get;

$\frac{1}{log(x)} \sim π'(x)$, where π'(x) represents the derivative of prime counting function according to x. (*note that this is only an assumption. Derivatives of two asymptotic functions don't have to be asymptotic again.*)

Now, π'(x) is the prime density function around x. For instance, around 100, approximately 1 of every log(100) numbers will be prime. Under this assumption we can say;

$$p_{2n-1} = p_{2n} - log(p_{2n})$$

If we substitute this into the top equation, we get;

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{p_{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{log(p_{2n})}{p_{2n}.(p_{2n} - log(p_{2n}))}$$
Using Riemann-Stieltjes integral method ($\sum_{p primes}^{N} f(p) \sim \int_{2}^{N} \frac{f(x)}{log(x)}dx$), above summation can be represented an integral like below:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{log(p_{2n})}{p_{2n}.(p_{2n} - log(p_{2n}))} \sim \frac{1}{2} \int_{2}^{\infty } \frac{dx}{x(x-logx)}$$

Since the indices increase by two, we wrote 1/2 at the beginning of the integral.

Here we can find a better approach if we add the first few terms manually and express the rest by integral;

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{p_{n}} \sim \sum_{n=1}^{x } \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{p_{n}} + O(\int_{x}^{\infty } \frac{dx}{x(x-logx)})$$

"O" is big O notation here. If we consider the result of this sum as a fixed number k,

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{x } \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{p_{n}} + \frac{1}{2} \int_{x}^{\infty } \frac{dt}{t(t-logt)}$$ $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } f(x) = k$$

I found the value of k = 0.269606356970929... by summing the values up to 100000000 **by hand** (I mean computer). And in the table below we compared the values ​​we obtained using this approach with the exact summation k for different x's.

| x | f(x) | $|\frac{f(x)-k}{k}|$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0.39737469802526604 | 0.473907004604176 |
| 10 | 0.28225778161237654 | 0.046925542793532 |
| 96 | 0.27035676966262771 | 0.002783364235657 |
| 1000 | 0.26958796380480553 | 0.000068222301321 |
| 10070 | 0.26960698064666632 | 0.000002313282759 |

In order to make a good comparison in the table above, we made sure to write the x values ​​that will return even values ​​when we calculate π(x). That's why it's not all round numbers.

With better π'(x) approximations, better bounds can be found.

Comment: what do you mean by $\pi'(x)$? Being a function that is constant between primes and jumping at them, trivially $\pi'(x)=0$ ae so cannot be asymptotic with $1/\log x$ at least as given...

Comment: Of course the function π(x) is not continuous, but when we say π'(x), we assume that this function is continuous and take its derivative. Think of it as if we were taking the derivative of the best function that is asymptotic to π(x). You can find more detail in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime-counting_function_in_terms_of_the_logarithmic_integral)

Comment: Then write it like that so use a different function name, put the error in etc - what you wrote is very handwaving and maybe useful as a heuristic but not more